# Display iframe div contents on parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions I've found to work for me. Basically, I need to get the contents of a div from an iframe, and write them to a div in the parent page. This is what I have:

```
<iframe src="slideshows/slideshow/case2.html" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" 
id="frame1" name="frame1"></iframe>

<div id="caption">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var caption = frame1.document.getElementById('slidecaption');
   document.write(caption);
   </script>
</div>
```

'slidecaption' is the name of Id in the iframe that I'm trying to grab.

All I get is "null". Is it because the iframe contents haven't loaded yet? If so, how do I delay until the iframe has loaded?

Thanks,
Scott

---

Thanks to both of you for your help. I figured it out, based on Márcio's idea:

I put the function in the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send() {
document.getElementById('slidecaption').innerHTML = 
frame1.document.getElementById('slidecaption').innerHTML}
</script>
```

And I put the call in the iframe document:

```
<body onload="parent.send();">
```

Regards,
Scott

Comment: where is frame1 declared in js?

Comment: As you can tell, I have little-to-no understanding of javascript. What you see above is all the js I've currently got in there. It's pieced together from a couple of examples. Everything I came across seemed to utilize the iframe name value without any kind of declaration.

Comment: Do you have control of the document in the frame and if **yes**, you can put a function in the `onload` event of the `body` ? If you can do these, I think you can do this the reverse way. Put a onload event on the frame doc and a function that gets the value of your object and send it to parent document with `parent` like this: `parent.document.getElementbyId('receiver').innerHTML = document.getElementById('target').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the only thing you need to do, but you certainly need to retrieve frame1 from the dom.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
   var caption = frame1.contentWindow.document.getElementById('slidecaption');
   document.write(caption);
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess there are additional problems: Declaring frame1 resulted in "Error: frame1.document is undefined".

Comment: Did you add the call to contentWindow?

Comment: Sorry—missed that. I added it and now it returns "null" again.